# Want to find path of a file from the application folder?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I want to find the path of the file or to access that file which is lying with the `.xaml` file and the `.cs` file.

I have my file `name.tx` in

```
C:\Users\Itsme\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\tsa\tsa\name.txt
```

Now i need to access this file using `StreamReader`. How could i access this file without providing the complete path.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the running application? `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationPath` I believe you are after

Comment: sorry but the `ApplicationPath` doesn't exist with `AppDpmain.CurrentDomain`.

Comment: @NeelBhasin you mean you want to access the running xaml/cs file

Comment: `BaseDirectory` sorry

Comment: @Kyle no i want to access one Text file lying with these files in same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to access file which is lying in the same Directory and I am asumming you are using WPF  you can use

```
  string _myDirectoryPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString().Substring(0, Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString().Length - 10).ToString() + @"\Myfile.txt";
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_myDirectoryPath);
```

**Update:**

I am not sure if other's will agree to this but I found a working solution.

Comment: sorry it will access the `Debug` directory of the application not the required one.

Comment: You generally want to use `Path.Combine` instead of the string concat

Comment: @NeelBhasin: Debug IS the application folder when you are running it from Visual Studio

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou can you tell me the path for that, what i need to mention in the path

Comment: @NeelBhasin Take a look at my updated answer I am not sure if this is the right way but i think it will work

Comment: Thanks but a little change ` string _myDirectoryPath =` `Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString().Substring(0,` `Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString().Length - 10).ToString() +` `@"\Myfile.txt";`
  `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_myDirectoryPath);`

Comment: but still need to check it with installer weather it works or not.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the question is, but if you're just tired of typing "C:\Users\Itsme\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\tsa\tsa\name.txt" all the time, try something like this.

```
    const string locationOfTextFiles = "C:\\Users\\Itsme\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\tsa\\tsa\\";

        var names = new string[]{ "nameOne", "nameTwo", "nameThree"};

        foreach(string name in names)
        {
             using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(locationOfTextFiles + name + ".txt"))
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
        }
```

Comment: What Kind of  solution is this ?